# Is Razor ServiceStack page documentation only related to if using the Razor Plugin?

Tags: servicestack

so I don't understand this.  So is this page stating all the things ServiceStack is no matter if you are using the razor extension from ServiceStack or is this based on IF you are using the razor extension when it talks about all the related MVC stuff further down the page?

http://razor.servicestack.net/#complete-stack

Answer (score 0):

The entire RazorRockstars project is a showcase for [ServiceStack's Razor Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Razor/) which as the opening paragraphs specify is added by NuGet with:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Razor
```

And enabled in ServiceStack with:

```
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
```

Further down that section explains what HTML Views are built-in and enabled by default, and that Razor support can be installed via NuGet:

> ServiceStack supports multiple view engines out-of-the-box: By default HtmlReport and Markdown Razor is pre-registered, whilst Razor support can be installed via NuGet.